# How to make a comparison between two variables like $4\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}$ and $\frac{2}{a}+2b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Both *a* and *b* are positive numbers. And how to make a comparison between two variables like $4\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}$ and $\frac{2}{a}+2b$? I tried subtraction and division, but both failed.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: By "compare" do you mean "write $a$ in terms of $b$" or something else entirely?

Comment: @Lanier Freeman By compare, I mean making a comparison to see who's bigger and who's smaller.

Comment: The title and the content of your question don´t match.

Comment: Its impossible to say from the given data....you missed a vital point $a>b$ or $a<b$?

Comment: "Both numbers are positive", that's what I got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for any positive $x,y$, we have $$x+y \ge 2\sqrt{xy}$$ from the AM-GM inequality.

Using this,

$$\frac{2}{a}+2b \ge 2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{a} \times 2b}=4\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}$$

Thus, the only thing we can definitively say is $$\frac{2}{a}+2b \ge 4\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}$$
Equality holds when $\frac{2}{a}=2b$, or $ab=1$.

Comment: Why the downvote?